# Tikz overrides one of my defined colors when I use left color, middle color and right color, how to fix this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I want to gradually change colours across the `double arrow` from white, to olive, to green. How to stop tikz from overriding my middle color?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=1cm, auto,baseline=-.5ex]

\node (dummy) at (-5,-8) {}; 

\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(dummy.center)}]

\node[double arrow,left color=white,middle color=olive!70, right color=green!35,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=3em, text centered,draw] {I \hspace{1cm} L O V E \hspace{1cm} M Y\hspace{1cm} J O B};

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should put the middle color after the other two.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Seems to work. You should post that as an answer?

Comment: @PeterGrill: I will add a cw answer: ultimately, it was just matter of opening the pgfmanual ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pgfmanual says:

> `/tikz/middle color=⟨color⟩   (no default)` 
>   This option specifies the color for the middle of an axis shading. It also sets the shade and `shading=axis` options, but it does not change the rotation angle.
>
> Note: Since both `top color` and `bottom color` change the `middle color`, this option should be given last if all of these options need to be given